# Header implementation variable redefinition does not show error

Tags: c++, ios

I am using a C++ header only class in iOS development (Xcode).

In A.hpp

```
class A {
    public:

        A() {
            B b;
        }

        void run() {
            b.run();
        }

    private:

        B b;
}
```

B is defined in a scientific computational library, and b.run() is expected to take noticeable time.

In ViewController.mm (or consider it as main.cpp)

```
A* a = new A(); a->run();
```

works fine (normally I'd expect some error for variable redefinition, here b is defined twice) but takes more than twice time than expected.

After removing `B b;` in `A()` everything works as it should be.

I am wondering if the reason for this strange thing caused by calling `b.run()` twice and compiler actually treat two definitions as separate initialization and call run on them separately. But Why compiler didn't catch such serious error?

Comment: You should check how much time does it take to initialize object of class B. b.run() is not getting called twice you can verify that easily, one of the best way is to write console output statement in `A::run() method`

Comment: There is no redefinition there by the way. This two variables are in different scopes.

Comment: It's bad style, but you can have a local variable that has the same name as a class member variable — they're different, and the local variable is the one that's used in the function.  If you expect the constructor for `A` to initialize the member variable `b`, you need to think again.  It's late here, but would `A() : b() { }` do the job you're after?

Comment: Probably `b`'s constructor does something which is affecting the runtime. What is in that constructor?  Alternatively, perhaps your code relies on uninitialized data and by chance the effect of this is a runtime change. To get a reliable answer post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The compiler didn't catch an error because there is no error. Read about (lexical) scope in your C++ book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is valid to define a local variable with the same name as a member variable. This will simply hide the member variable within that scope (you can still access it by this->b) .

Answer (score 0):

First there is no variable redefinition in your code because the declaration in A() has local scope and doesn't contradict with the declaration of **'b'** as a class member(it just hides the member variable with in that scope). Second from the given information i don't see why this takes twice as much time unless the constructor of the class B calls its run() method or does something time consuming. you should check the constructor of the Class B and what it does inside.